# Sort by publish date, even if publish date is tomorrow or 2 years ago

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I'm trying to make this as intuitive for my customer as possible. They already have many news articles they need moved to this new Umbraco 7 site. I want the following to happen:

- If they make a news article and set the "Publish At" date to tomorrow, it will not show on the page until tomorrow.
- If they do not set a "Publish At" date, it should look at the published date (you would not fill out the "Publish At" date if you want it published now)
- If they edit an old article, it should not affect the sorting at all (meaning `UpdateDate` shouldn't work)
- If there are `n` articles all released today, and someone publishes a news article with "Publish At" set to yesterday, it will put the news article before the 3 new ones

Is something like this possible, without creating an additional property? That's, in my opinion, just going to confuse the person.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently the only way to do this, is by creating an additional field with type Date. I was hoping I could do this through the built in ones from Umbraco.

Turns out there are no "this is the exact date when this article was published" property I can access, while still getting this to work. It does give the creator a few options regarding the sorting, as it's very easy to sort them by date now.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your scenario, here are my replies to each of your questions

- If they make a news article and set the "Publish At" date to tomorrow, it will not show on the page until tomorrow.

**Ans** - If they set the Publish At date to tomorrow and just **save** that article, then it would never be published until tomorrow. If the page is already published, then it needs to be unpublished first.

- If they do not set a "Publish At" date, it should look at the published date (you would not fill out the "Publish At" date if you want it published now)

**Ans** - They just need to click save and publish to publish the article now.

- If they edit an old article, it should not affect the sorting at all (meaning UpdateDate shouldn't work)

**Ans** - You can handle this in ContentService_Saving event. Refer - [ContentService Events](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/events/contentservice-events)

- If there are n articles all released today, and someone publishes a news article with "Publish At" set to yesterday, it will put the news article before the 3 new ones

**Ans** - Taken from [This Umbraco forum](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/razor/39658-Sorting-content-by-Last-published-date) . Adding this for everyone here as well.

I would create the property SortDate, and another true/false property PublishMode.  While SortDate is self-explanatory, I would set PublishMode to true once you are done drafting and adding content to a page.  So if I've written a page and only need to fix typos and reword after it has been published, this would be set to true.

I would then hook into a republish event and add some logic like so:

```
if (page's type alias is a post) && (PublishMode is false) {
if (DateCompare(page.CreateDate, page.UpdateDate) >= 0 
{ page.SortDate = page.CreateDate } 
else {page.SortDate = page.UpdateDate}
}
```

So then after you're done, you can have a date that will be sorted depending on the "mode" of the document while it is being republished.

As a side note, even if you don't have a date picked, the datepicker datatype automatically sets itself to something like "01/01/0011".  So it would never return a null value.

Also, the datepicker datatype is not a DateTime object.  So to use the DateCompare, you have to parse each date property into a DateTime object like:

```
DateCompare(DateTime.Parse(Page.CreateDate.ToString("r"), DateTime.Parse(Page.UpdateDate.ToString("r"))
```

Hope this helps!!

Thanks

Comment: All of this sounds like waaay too much work for the user. What is the user accidentally hits publish? The user should only have to input a date for when the publishing date is, and it should only sort by that. The only way that is possible, is by creating another date property on the document type.

Comment: It depends on the person using the CMS. Mostly the content guys are aware of such things like when to hit save and when to publish. Rest is your choice as well how you want to maintain your system.